# Unable to get Toad (MySQL) to autofill NOT NULL timestamp and INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT columns when importing CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, toad

I'm trying to import a CSV with data in the following format into a Toad MySQL database and at the same time auto populate the date_created and date_updated columns with current timestamps (datatype = 'timestamp'), and the publication_id column with unique integers that auto increment.

i.e. I'm trying to insert this CSV file...

```
publication notes   date_created    date_updated    publication_id
book        test            
newspaper   test            
website     test
```

...aiming to get this added to the database:

```
publication notes   date_created    date_updated    publication_id
book        test    26-07-16 10:56  26-07-16 10:56  1
newspaper   test    26-07-16 10:56  26-07-16 10:56  2
website     test    26-07-16 10:56  26-07-16 10:56  3
```

I am using the Import Wizard. (and getting the errors listed in the endnote *)

date_created and date_updated columns are NOT NULL, default value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

The publication_id column is INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

Any help you could provide so that I can do this would be greatly appreciated, thanks! (I'm a beginner)

*

Errors:

1

> Value '' at row #1 cannot be convert to type TIMESTAMP of column date_created
>   Do you want to cancel the import and re-map the column? Click no to ignore the current error(s) and any additional errors and continue importing.

2

> Value '' at row #1 cannot be convert to type INT(5) UNSIGNED of column publication_id
>   Do you want to cancel the import and re-map the column? Click no to ignore the current error(s) and any additional errors and continue importing.